# Histogram question: How do we choose a perfect histogram?

Tags: self-study, histogram

20 students from a school were randomly selected to study the dollar
amount that they spend on purchasing soft drink in a typical week. The data
collected (in dollars):

```
$24, $35, $17, $21, $24, $37, $26, $46, $58, $30,
$32, $13, $12, $38, $41, $43, $44, $27, $53, $27
```

Some graphical representations are created based on the above data

Figures 1 to 4 are shown below.

Which do you consider an appropriate histogram? You can choose more then 1.

[image: Histogram.]

This is an actual quiz question but I find it to be so poorly worded I cannot understand a single bit. Can anyone help?

Comment: You may have to wait a bit, questions aren't usually answered in the first hour. What is it that confuses you about the question? Is this an essay question?

Comment: The histograms in the lower row are incorrectly drawn: they do not depict all the data, no matter how you interpret the vertical axis.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldnt say the question is poorly worded.  It's just that the differences of the histograms are subtle, and can be missed.

The problem asks:

```
 Which do you consider an appropriate histogram? You can choose more then 1.
```

If you look at Figure 1 and Figure 2, at first glance they look identical.  However, they have a major difference. Can you spot it?  (Hint: Read the labels carefully).

Then between Figure 3 and Figure 4, you have an analogous situation.  In each case only one is appropriate, given the data.

Can you take it from here?